# svg will stretch in Microsoft edge

Tags: css, svg, microsoft-edge

I have created a svg that will stretch in Internet explorer prior to Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome.

- In Edge, it will stretch in both directions (not expected, the background image of the div should be 100% 100%, but the svg rendition itself should not)

[image: it output]

- In Google Chrome, it keeps aspect ratio (expected) and aligns to top (not expected, should be vertically centered).

[image: chrome output]

Why are my two expectations failing?

The svg has a xml node of name `<svg>` with the following attribute (added with a text editor):

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
```

css

```
div
{
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    background: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/o050kltcraffr46/logo_preserve_mid_mid.svg?dl=1") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/szs0e29j/4/

SVG data (on request):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   id="Lager_1"
   x="0px"
   y="0px"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
   viewBox="0 0 372.4 38.7"
   style="enable-background:new 0 0 372.4 38.7;"
   xml:space="preserve"
   inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   sodipodi:docname="logo.svg"><metadata
   id="metadata47"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
       rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
         rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:title></dc:title></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
   id="defs45" /><sodipodi:namedview
   pagecolor="#ffffff"
   bordercolor="#666666"
   borderopacity="1"
   objecttolerance="10"
   gridtolerance="10"
   guidetolerance="10"
   inkscape:pageopacity="0"
   inkscape:pageshadow="2"
   inkscape:window-width="978"
   inkscape:window-height="629"
   id="namedview43"
   showgrid="false"
   inkscape:zoom="0.76799141"
   inkscape:cx="379.5689"
   inkscape:cy="204.62955"
   inkscape:window-x="256"
   inkscape:window-y="55"
   inkscape:window-maximized="0"
   inkscape:current-layer="Lager_1" />
<style
   type="text/css"
   id="style3">
    .st0{fill:#006633;}
    .st1{fill:#2FAC66;}
</style>


<path
   class="st0"
   d="m 3.5393357,4.5729924 c 0,0 117.9056743,44.3370146 159.8334743,8.1788026 96.58369,-15.3993842 169.82631,-5.3997844 201.21601,0 0,0 -166.90922,-8.5807957 -162.58254,13.199471 C 142.44634,42.550602 65.098047,36.617023 3.5393357,4.5729924 z"
   id="path37"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   style="fill:#006633"
   sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />


</svg>
```

Comment: Any chance you could post the `svg` xml data as well? You will need a `viewBox` and a `width` or `height` property set on those for them to scale properly, all other data is mostly discarded.

Comment: @somethinghere I have now added the svg data and corrected the css so it reflects the jsfiddle.

Comment: I must say that the svg attributes saying width="100%" and height="100%" is very suspicious. Removing those attributes did on the other side not change the behaviour.

Comment: Indeed, percentage based width and heights are not valid for SVG (or at the very lest not consistently useable) - they need the value of `width` and `height` to create the correct viewBox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of, lets clean up your SVG to simplify it a little bit - the output combination of meta info from multiple sources makes it hard to pin point problems: This is basically your svg:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 372.4 38.7" width="375" height="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="m 3.5393357,4.5729924 c 0,0 117.9056743,44.3370146 159.8334743,8.1788026 96.58369,-15.3993842 169.82631,-5.3997844 201.21601,0 0,0 -166.90922,-8.5807957 -162.58254,13.199471 C 142.44634,42.550602 65.098047,36.617023 3.5393357,4.5729924 z" fill="#006633" />
</svg>
```

An important bit, however, is that your `width` *needs* a pixel based value - otherwise scaling will not work consistently. I have noticed that for older IE, it might be best to actually predefine the `height` as well. I have used the x-width and y-height values used in the `viewBox` property (but rounded up). You also *need* the `viewBox` property, as well as a `xmlns` tag (that last one, I seem to remember it working without, but either way, this works cross-browser).

This is the test page I used (I was not able to convert this into a base-64 style string even though I found many articles saying it would work with `data:image/svg+xml;enctype=utf-8,/* URL encoded SVG string */`, but I couldn't get it to work), so try the following code on your own computer in combination with the above code!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  body, html { height: 100%; }
  body { 
   background: url('mySVG.svg');
   background-size: contain;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>There is nothing on this page, it requires a seperate SVG file you can find higher up in this Stack Overflow Post.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tested this in IE9, Edge, Safari 8 and Chrome and this SVG worked cross-browser. So in this post you'll find the minimum requirements for an SVG to work almost everywhere.

#### Addition: Another Culprit?

There is an issue with what you are expecting of your CSS. When you assume that your `svg` will simply be an image when it gets drawn to the background, then Edge's behaviour absolutely makes sense. `background-size: 100% 100%` would stretch *any* image. So to center and *not* stretch it, use `auto`:

```
div {
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    background: url("url.svg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
    // This is full height
    background-size: auto 100%;
    // This is stretching it
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    // This is full width
    background-size: 100% auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Here a quick example showing what I mean:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
pre {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  height: calc((100% - 2px) / 3);
  margin-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
pre#bg1 {
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
pre#bg2 {
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
pre#bg3 {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<pre id="bg1">background-size: 100% auto;</pre>
<pre id="bg2">background-size: auto 100%;</pre>
<pre id="bg3">background-size: 100% 100%;</pre>
```

Comment: I already found a work-around as my own "answer" suggests. However, I tried to use your cleaned up svg in http://jsfiddle.net/szs0e29j/9/ . It did the vertical centering in chrome but did not change behavior in edge.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the responsibility of keeping aspect ratio from the svg renderer to the element rendering by using `background-size: contain`. This is not an answer to the question but a description of how I proceeded/worked around the problem.

```
div
{
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    background: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/o050kltcraffr46/logo_preserve_mid_mid.svg?dl=1") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/szs0e29j/7/

Comment: Sorry but the answer here is exactly what I had described above only you decided to use `contain`. Like I said, an SVG is an image like any other and its width and height are stretched in either direction if you use `100% 100%`. I have tested my answer in Edge and it works.

Comment: How does the jsfiddle I made look in your Edge? The question was how to do this using background-size: 100% 100%. Previous browser versions has rendered the svg with correct aspect ratio despite using that background-size.

Comment: Exactly how my answer looked except not constrained in a smaller box.

Comment: I will tick your answer, never saw that you used contain. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Background-size `100% 100%` **does not preserve aspect ratio** - only if your box is in a 1:1 aspect ratio to your image. The `contain` keyword works, yes, I did not mention it, but I have clearly stated that using a different background-size (like one with auto) yields different and more predictable results.

Comment: background-size: 100% 100% actually preserved aspect ratio before Edge, try the first jsfiddle in IE11. It is just the element containing the svg output that goes 100% wide and high. The aspect keeping mechanism is a svg feature, not css and was only true for svg files, not pixel images.

Comment: Thats not actually the correct behaviour anyhow - `100% 100%` means it needs to have full height and width of the container it is being stretched in. Thats what `100%` means in any other context in CSS and should mean here.